# Supressing browser generated alert boxes using Javascript

Tags: browser, javascript

I want to stop an alert box being popped up by the browser using Javascript, as I find it bothersome. Is there any way to do this? Perhaps an addon, or script?

Comment: Is this an alert box on a specific site, or do you want to stop any alert boxes appearing in your browser?   Which browser are you using?

Comment: The browser is mobile safari and it is an alert box on a specific site.

Answer (score 2):

One can interpret the question in two ways:

1.I want to use javascript to stop alert boxes

You can override the `alert` function so it'll do nothing:

```
window.alert = function () {}
```

Unfortunately, the usual fiend (IE) will not accept this, as `alert` is special voodoo-magic to it and not a regular function.

2.I want to stop alert boxes spawned by javascript

You can't turn off specific features. You either disable javascript, or deal with it.

Comment: Zirak, Y U NO GREASEMONKEY?

Comment: Hi All,Thanks for your comments. The real scenario is like i have a line of code in javascript window.location=some url. now i want to stop any type of alert box generated due to problem in url and execute the code silently.

Answer (score 2):

in Firefox and Chrome this option is built in (after the first popup, if consecutive popups are your concern)

[image]
[image]

or if you use FireFox you can install greasemonkey and [this user script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/58252)

OR if you are the webpage owner and you want to disable alerts on your own site (for what reason I don't know)

`window.alert = function(){};` will likely do it (not sure about IE.. but thats a start).